# Directed graph of build road system

Tags: directed-graph

The City is reforming its road system in hope of improving traffic. Whether it will be an actual improvement or not is out of our scope, but they are turning to us for a sanity check: Whenever they come up with a new draft for their street map, which may contain one-way streets, is it true that from every intersection you can reach every other intersection while complying with street directions?
If not, then they know they need to re-draft.
So they need an algorithm for: Input the street map—intersections, the streets between them, and street directions (all represented by adjacency lists, say); output true if the street map satisfies “for all intersections u and v, there is a direction-complying path from u to v”, else output false. The algorithm must finish in O(# of intersections + # of streets) time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

where each node is your intersection and each edge is the street.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99237/find-if-we-can-reach-all-nodes-in-a-directed-graph-starting-from-one-node-s